# pop up a view when i clicked button on table view cell

Tags: objective-c

I have a button on table view cell if I click the button a pop up view will be appeared and the remaining cells will be animated to downwards like animation.and the cell having sub views it will open like a plist in ios if i click the sub view cell it will open the next level sub cells. The tableview must be like below images

[image: The table view must be like this]

[image: Table view]

[image]

Cells and sub-cells must be like this. Can any one assist me?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before. Just use the following code. Create a custom cell class having the cell and followed view in the cell view but show only what is to be shown by using heightforrowatindexpath method uitableview class. Here is the code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    if (checkHeight == indexPath.row)
        return 185;
    else
        return 80;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    FAQCell *cell = (FAQCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FAQCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = myCell;
        myCell = nil;
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [cell.quesText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"CaviarDreams" size:16]];
    [cell.ansText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"CaviarDreams" size:16]];


    // check for the row for which the background color has to be changed
    if (checkHeight == indexPath.row)
        [cell.bgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3333 green:0.7373 blue:0.4588 alpha:1.0]];
    else
        [cell.bgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.9176 green:0.3765 blue:0.2980 alpha:1.0]];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Tableview Delegate Methods

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Deselect cell
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];
    checkHeight = indexPath.row;

    // reload the data of the table
    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, tableView.numberOfSections)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: hi Thanks for the code but my requirement is different as shown above . it will open the sub cells and the entire data is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this custom view -

1. [Custom Tree View](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ratreeview)
2. [Expandable Table View](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jkexpandtableview)